# VBA Want to compare 2 date column and 2 value column to create one of each

Tags: vba, excel

I want to compare each date in the row, take the highest, sort them by farest to nearest, and then do the same thing with the values.

There's my code

```
Sub Intersection()

Dim nombre As Integer
Dim tableauDate(1 To 130) As Date
Dim tableauValeur(1 To 130) As String
Dim incrementeurForeach As Integer

nombre = 115
incrementeurForeach = 1

For incrementeur = 0 To nombre
    If Range("A" & incrementeur).Value = Range("C" & incrementeur).Value Then
        tableauDate(incrementeur) = Range("A" & incrementeur).Value
        If Range("B" & incrementeur).Value > Range("D" & incrementeur).Value Then
            tableauValeur(incrementeur) = Range("B" & incrementeur).Value
        Else
            tableauValeur(incrementeur) = Range("D" & incrementeur).Value
        End If
    Else
        If Range("A" & incrementeur).Value > Range("C" & incrementeur).Value Then
            tableauDate(incrementeur) = Range("A" & incrementeur).Value
        Else
            tableauDate(incrementeur) = Range("C" & incrementeur).Value
        End If
    End If

Next incrementeur

For Each valeur In tableauDate

    Range("A", incrementeurForeach).Value = tableauDate(incrementeurForeach)
    Range("B", incrementeurForeach).Value = tableauValeur(incrementeurForeach)

    incrementeurForeach = incrementeurForeach + 1

Next valeur
End Sub
```

And there's a part of the table

```
         A                  B               C               D
1        Date A         Prix A          Date B          Prix B
2        2000-01-31         34,84 $     2000-01-31  48,07 $ 
3        2000-05-31         29,22 $     2000-02-29  39,15 $ 
4        2000-06-30         29,00 $     2000-03-31  43,46 $ 
5        2000-07-31         30,25 $     2000-04-30  43,62 $ 
6        2000-08-31         33,27 $     2000-05-31  47,27 $
```

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: What is the issue with your current code? Can you post a sample file to help us help you?

Comment: Change `For incrementeur = 0 To nombre` to `For incrementeur = 2 To nombre`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to clean up your code a little bit which may help you or others.

There were some errors, for example `incrementeur` must begin at `1` because `Range("A" & incrementeur)` will error if `incrementeur = 0`.  This required some minor changes elsewhere in the code.

I am not sure what the specific problem is, however I notice that you are only populating the `tableauValeur` if Date A = Date B.

```
Sub Intersection()

Dim nombre As Integer
Dim tableauDate(1 To 130) As Date
Dim tableauValeur(1 To 130) As String
Dim valeur as Variant
Dim incrementeurForeach As Integer
Dim dateA As Date
Dim dateB As Date
Dim prixA As Variant
Dim prixB As Variant

nombre = 115
incrementeurForeach = 1  

For incrementeur = 2 To nombre  'change to "2"'
    'Add some variables to make the code more legible.'
    dateA = Range("A" & incrementeur).Value
    dateB = Range("c" & incrementeur).Value
    prixA = Range("B" & incrementeur).Value
    prixB = Range("D" & incrementeur).Value

    'Rewrite the expressions using the variables'.
    ' Also favor a Select Case instead of nested IF/Then.'
    Select Case dateA
        Case Is = dateB
            tableauDate(incrementeur) = dateA
            If prixA > prixB Then
                tableauValeur(incrementeur - 1) = prixA
            Else
                tableauValeur(incrementeur - 1) = prixB
            End If

        Case Is > dateB
            tableauDate(incrementeur - 1) = dateA

        Case Else:
            tableauDate(incrementeur - 1) = dateB

    End Select

Next incrementeur


Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet  'I add a new worksheet to debug, you can remove this if necessary'

For Each valeur In tableauDate

'I also change the way you specify the Ranges, to use OFFSET.
    Range("A1").Offset(incrementeurForEach,0).Value = tableauDate(incrementeurForeach)
    Range("B1").Offset(incrementeurForEach,0).Value = tableauValeur(incrementeurForeach)

    incrementeurForeach = incrementeurForeach + 1

Next valeur

End Sub
```

Comment: NOw, the code has created 130 sheets, and I do know which part to change. I'm a beginner in VBA. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I updated the code -- it should now add ONE sheet, before the `For Each valeur in tableauDate` loop. Previously, it was adding a sheet for each `valeur`, which was not correct.

Comment: Hi,Now it work for a part of the date, but not for all of them. Also, Prices are not there, at side of dates...   There are 130 dates on my list which appear on my sheet, but en fact, there are 115+100 dates (2 columns). Thank you for your help.

Comment: I previously mention that you are only populating the tableauValeur if Date A = Date B. This is not something I can solve, since it is dependent on you to provide the correct logic.